# How can I consistently read and change each individual pixel using OpenCV with Python when reading pixel value?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

Hello and thank you for reading my question! I have noticed that when I attempt to read the pixel value before changing it using "(b,g,r) = image[c,r]" that python will skip the majority of the pixels? Is there any reason for this and is there any workaround? What I am working towards is an attempt to enhance any reds in the image but it won't work if python is skipping pixels...

```
import argparse
import cv2
import numpy as np

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
           help="Path to the image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

image = cv2.imread(args["image"])

for r in range(image.shape[1]):
    for c in range(image.shape[0]):
        count = count + 1

    #without this line the code works fine but when it is included it 
    #skips most of the pixels...
    (b,g,r) = image[c,r]

    canvas[c, r] = (255, 255, 255)

    cv2.imshow("changed canvas", canvas)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Conflict between your iteration variable `r` and the red color channel variable `r`, rename one.

Comment: Thanks! Wow can't believe I missed that...

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage is using numpy's ndarray function item and itemset

to read the red value at pixel (0,0):

```
#note instead of rgb opencv writes the order as bgr so red is last
image.item(0,0,2)
```

to set:

```
image.itemset((0,0,2), 250)
```